# using variable and expressions in search and replace command

Tags: vim, vi

I am trying to set some key mapping/macros to comment/uncomment blocks of text in my .vimrc but I can't manage to make it work.

I define some variables:

```
let g:comment_id='~'
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.c,*.cpp,*.cxx,*.h,*.hpp,*.hxx,*.ipp let b:comment_open='//'
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.f90,*.F90 let b:comment_open='!'
```

And then I try differents ways to use them but everytime it fails:

```
noremap <silent> ,cc :s/^/<C-R>=(b:comment_open.g:comment_id)/<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>
noremap <silent> ,uc :s/<C-R>=(b:comment_open.g:comment_id)//<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>
```

->
E15: Invalid expression: /,
E15: Invalid expression: (b:comment_open.g:comment_id)//

```
noremap <silent> ,cc :s/^/<C-R>=(b:comment_open.g:comment_id)<CR>/<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>
noremap <silent> ,uc :s/<C-R>=(b:comment_open.g:comment_id)<CR>//<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>
```

->
E488: Trailing characters

```
noremap <silent> ,cc :s/^/\=(b:comment_open.g:comment_id)/<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>
noremap <silent> ,uc :s/\=(b:comment_open.g:comment_id)//<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>
```

->
cc: ok,
uc:
E64: \= follows nothing,
E476: Invalid command

I fact I can't understand how 'C-R' and \= work and mean...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
nnoremap <silent> ,cc :s/^/\=b:comment_open.g:comment_id/<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>
nnoremap <silent> ,uc :s@\V<c-r>=escape(b:comment_open.g:comment_id,'\@')<cr>@@<cr>:nohlsearch<cr>
```

Reference: `:help sub-replace-expression`

It is necessary in the pattern to turn verynomagic on to escape all special characters, and even with that you need to escape both the delimiter and the backslash.

Comment: This one<br/>

    noremap <silent> ,cc :s/^/\=b:comment_open.g:comment_id/<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>  <br/>

is ok for ,cc but ,uc fails, I get E64: \= follows nothing, E476: Invalid command when using:  <br/>

    noremap <silent> ,uc :s/\=(b:comment_open.g:comment_id)//<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>  <br/>

Thank you for helping

Comment: with the uncomment macro, I get an error:  
E33: No previous substitute regular expression  
E476: Invalid command

Comment: ok it works with something else than tilde. So why one has to use sometime '\=' and sometimes 'C-R'? Thank you very much

Comment: There is an `escape()` function: `escape(b:comment_open.g:comment_id, '\@')`.